# Passing local variable to batch with returnStdout in jenkins pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins-pipeline

When i try to substitute date_append variable in batch command as shown below, its not retrieving the date exactly, instead it shows as Snapshot-${date_append}.onp

where is the exact issue?

```
 stage('test') {
        steps {
                script
                {
                    date_append= "${new Date().format('yyyyMMdd_hhmmss')}"
                    echo "${date_append}"

                    issue=bat(label: '', returnStdout: true, script: '''echo off
             "C:\\Desktop\\eme.exe" /v 
         /source:SYS/dbname@localhost:port/env{test} AS SYSDBA 
        /target:C:\\desktop\\file-${date_append}.xml{test}  
       /scriptfile:C:\\script\\oldscript.sql
        @IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 61 (
   @echo "issue is FALSE"
  )''')
              }     
           }
       }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a [tag:batch-file]...

Comment: Its a pipeline code. Where inside script iam executing bat ,issue=bat(label: '', returnStdout: true, script: '''echo off
             "C:\\Desktop\\eme.exe" /v 
         /source:SYS/dbname@localhost:port/env{test} AS SYSDBA 
        /target:C:\\desktop\\file-${date_append}.xml{test}  
       /scriptfile:C:\\script\\oldscript.sql
        IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 61 (
   echo "issue is FALSE"
  )''')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me!!!

```
  issue=bat(label: '', returnStdout: true, script: """echo off
         "C:\\Desktop\\eme.exe" /v
     /source:SYS/dbname@localhost:port/env{test} AS SYSDBA
    /target:C:\\desktop\\file-${date_append}.xml{test}
   /scriptfile:C:\\script\\oldscript.sql
    IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 61 (
   echo \"issue is FALSE\"
  )""")
```

Answer (score 4):

To use a variable inside shell script in goovy you need to use GStrings, which is `"` instead of `'`

So your code just needs to swap the use of `'''` for `"""` and either escape your current use of `"` or swap them for `'`, (Below I have both swapped and escaped your double quotes for example purposes):

```
issue=bat(label: '', returnStdout: true, script: """echo off
             'C:\\Desktop\\eme.exe' /v
         /source:SYS/dbname@localhost:port/env{test} AS SYSDBA
        /target:C:\\desktop\\file-${date_append}.xml{test}
       /scriptfile:C:\\script\\oldscript.sql
        @IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 61 (
   @echo \"issue is FALSE\"
  )""")
```

For more reading on GStrings see: http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes

Comment: Thank you @metalisticpain . its taking the variable as required but somewhere the filename/directory is not readable since i was facing below issue when i execute this command and its moving to if loop by default,                                                            *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.*

Comment: I don't know on that one sorry. Perhaps raise a new question

Comment: Unless you need to do more \ escapes? on `C:\\\\`

Comment: It worked as below, Thanks you!!                                                                                        issue=bat(label: '', returnStdout: true, script: """echo off
             "C:\\Desktop\\eme.exe" /v
         /source:SYS/dbname@localhost:port/env{test} AS SYSDBA
        /target:C:\\desktop\\file-${date_append}.xml{test}
       /scriptfile:C:\\script\\oldscript.sql
        IF  %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 61 (
   echo \"issue is FALSE\"
  )""")